# How to get the field values using the Modified javascript step in pentaho?

Tags: javascript, java, pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I'm trying to get the field values and field meta data ie., field properties,

Using the following script I'm able to find the field type and field properties. Now im trying to check if there is any null value in the a particular field, so that I can replace the field value with the default values based on the field type.

How can I read the field values without using the input fields ie.,hard coding (ie., to use some inbuilt functions as of how we get the meta data)[following is the snip of code that i used to get the field properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6kFHl.jpg)

Comment: Get a screenshot using a tool like the 'snipping tool'. Don't use a phone camera. Even don't include pictures of the code. provide the code as a snippet.

Comment: Apart from the comment made by @Pawara Siriwardhane on not using screenshots when you can put the code directly in your question properly formated, I think your question needs more context to understand the problem, for example, why do you need to use the Modified javascript step that you can't achieve with normal steps in Pentaho. You can use the "If field value is null" step previous to the Modified javascript step to handle the null values in your fields properly.